# Angularjs debugging of [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e?

Tags: angularjs

How can I debug Angular's error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module zvApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=e
    at http://app.dev/build/js/vendor-53eec796.js:3:19384
```

There is some provider unknown, but which one? I can't find an easy way how to debug this. Tried it all.. Think it's a bug in a 3rd party package, but can't be sure without debugging.

Comment: Just check your dependency injections, you have minification unsafe injection.

Comment: replace `angular.min.js` with `angular.js` to get better error messages, but this is most definitely an issue with the way you are injecting scripts.  the full `angular.js` will at least tell you which injection is broken.

Comment: @dfsq, what do you mean? Im not that big of a angular hero.

Comment: @Claies already doing the non-minified version, but that output is no help.

Comment: use `ng-strict-di` on the root element and run your application with non minified code, it will complain the places where you are missing explicit dependency annotation.

Comment: the code you have posted here is the full error message? the provider is named `e`?

Comment: @Claies it is minified, so variable (argument to the constructor) will just have short names, hard to figure out what is going on where.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most possibly your issue is with lack of [explicit dependency annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) (unless **[ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)** is used with minification), using *array syntax* (`.service('myService', ['$http', function($http){...`) or *`$inject` static property* (`MyService.$inject=['$q']`) on the constructor. It is very hard to find it late in the game or in the minified code. So general practice would be to use **[`ng-strict-di`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection)** with `ng-app` directive and while your development or running application with non minified code it will throw more informative error in the places where you lack explicit dependency annotation.

Example:-

If using `ng-app` then,

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

If manually bootstrapping, then specify it as option.

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```

By turning on `strict-di` angular injector will specifically check for explicit annotation before instantiating and lack of which will break the application with error, this more often helps prevent these issue or catch them early in the game. Generally turning on `strict-di` option is helpful (and no need to remove it for production btw) in catching lack of dependency injection almost every definition including run, config and even the resolve functions (used with routers, modals etc).

Comment: whoooo, this will become the best help on the web for this. thnx!